# how to draw live line graph using mysql query in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pymysql

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import style

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.animation as animation

style.use("fivethirtyeight")

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

db=pymysql.connect("localhost","root","root","bounce")

cursor=db.cursor()

cursor.execute("select day,visitors,bounce_rate from bounce1")

data=cursor.fetchall()

df = pd.read_sql('select day,visitors,bounce_rate from bounce1', con=db)

print(df)

df.set_index("day",inplace=True)

xar = []

yar = []

zar = []

"""for eachLine in df:

    if len(eachLine)>1:

            x,y,z=eachLine.split('')

            xar.append(int(x))

            yar.append(int(y))

            xar.append(int(z))"""

ax1.clear()

ax1.plot(xar,yar,zar)

  #  ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1)


plt.show()
```

I have tried this code but line is not printing

[image]

Comment: You need to break down your problem in simple parts if you want help, plus you'll see you'll probably manage to solve your problem on your own. Have you tried plotting a simple static plot? Then plot with static data from your db? The try an animation with random data, and only then try to replace the random data with the db data